# Issue in parsing an XML in JSP

Tags: java, xml, jsp, scriptlet

I am trying to parse a XML in a JSP using DOM approach. Below is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<apis xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
    <api name="getFormFields" requesttype ="GET">
         <url>/fieldtype/</url>       
         <parameters>
             <parameter><![CDATA[fieldtype=textbox&fieldId=8668376496495]]></parameter>
          </parameters>
    </api>
 </apis>
```

I want to read `<parameters>` tag, display paramater value, but not able to do so. Below is the JSP I am using to do this. This JSP displays URL, `<api>` `name` and `requesttype`. I want `<parameters>` also and on click of submit I want to send this data to a script. I am failing to do this.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@page import="org.w3c.dom.*, javax.xml.parsers.* ,java.io.File,java.util.*, javax.servlet.http.*"%>
<%
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(
    "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Desktop\\apc.xml"));
%>
<%!
    public boolean isTextNode(Node n){
        return n.getNodeName().equals("#text");
    }
%>
<html>
<head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title><fmt:message key="welcome.title"/></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/blueprint/screen.css" />" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/blueprint/print.css" />" type="text/css" media="print">

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var xmlStr="\n";

function showData()
{
    alert('here');


xmlStr="\n";
var pageNumber;
if(document.forms[0].services[0].checked||document.forms[0].services[1].checked)
{
 if(document.forms[0].services[1].checked)
 {
     alert(document.forms[0].services[0].checked);
     var urlData = document.getElementById('urlData').value;
        alert(urlData);

  }

}
}
</script>
<form name="myForm">
<h2><font color='green'>List of Service Api</font></h2>
        <table border="2">
            <tr>

                <th>Methods</th>
                    <th>Request Type</th>
                <th>URL</th>

            </tr>
                <%

                    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                    Element  element = doc.getDocumentElement(); 
                    NodeList apiNodes = element.getChildNodes();     
                    for (int i=0; i<apiNodes.getLength(); i++){
                        Node nodeApi = apiNodes.item(i);

                        if (isTextNode(nodeApi))
                            continue;
                        NodeList url = nodeApi.getChildNodes(); 
                %>

            <tr>
            <td>

                 <input type="hidden" name="apiNames" value="<%= apiNodes.item(i).getAttributes().item(0) %>"/>
                <input type="radio" name="services" value="0"><%= apiNodes.item(i).getAttributes().item(0) %></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="requestType" value="<%= apiNodes.item(i).getAttributes().item(1) %>"/><%= apiNodes.item(i).getAttributes().item(1) %></td>
                <%
                    for (int j=0; j<url.getLength(); j++ ){
                        Node node = url.item(j);
                        if ( isTextNode(node)) 
                            continue;
                %>

                <td><input type="hidden" name="urlData" value="<%= node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue() %>"/><%= node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue() %></td>
                <%
                    } 
                %>



            </tr>
            <br>


                <%
                    }
                %>
                <td> <button name="SubmitRequest" onclick="showData();">Submit Request</button></td>
        </table>
     <textarea name="response" cols="150" rows="120"></textarea>
       </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For someone to help you need to tell us what actually happens.  Do you get an error message? What servlet container are you running in (Tomcat?) What is in the logs?

Comment: Also, I would recommend getting rid of the scriplets and do the processing in the proper java class.

Comment: in ui console i can see the listing of url,requesttype,api name ,and on click of a api and on submit i need to send the data selected having url,api name,request type to showData() ,but i am not at all getting these values.I running this in tomcat ,this is just like a static page

Comment: @kris the requirement is to use scripts ,as such using this,i am sure i am dong something wrong in jsp.Please help me out,i am not able to identify the mistake

Comment: scripts != scriplets, if someone has created the requirement to use scriplets I would quit my (job/university/college) :)

Comment: yes its scriplets ,i wil certainly move the code to java later but for now i need it

Answer (score 0):

Parsing XML files using pure DOM traversing is always pain. Use for example JAXB to avoid this.

But if you really want to, I suggest to try to a) access XML tags using their names rather than using their position in the DOM tree and b) accessing the content using `getContextText()`. This works fine for rather simple XML files. One example you can find below, the other values are then similar:

```
    <%
    NodeList apis = doc.getElementsByTagName("api");
    for (int i=0; i < apis.getLength(); i++) {
      Element api = (Element) apis.item(i); //the cast works if you really used a tag name in getElementsByTagName()
      Element url = (Element) api.getElementsByTagName("url").item(0);
      String urlContent = url.getTextContext().trim(); //trim gets rid of nasty whitespace like \n 

    %>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="urlData" value="<%=urlContent%>"/><%=urlContent%></td>
    <%
    }
    %>
```